# How to shutdown embedded Derby which is defined as a DataSource properly on WildFly

Tags: derby, wildfly

When I defined a Derby DataSource on WildFly normally, db.lck file is left undeleted and it indicates the database was not shutdown properly at every shutdown of WildFly. because embedded Derby requires a special shutdown procedure that is acquiring a new connection with JDBC URL which ended with ";shutdown=true" string.

So, I need something like a shutdown-hook which executes the shutdown procedure. I found that old JBoss have a way to achieve it:

https://developer.jboss.org/wiki/SetUpADerbyDatasource
http://grepcode.com/file/repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org.jboss.jbossas/jboss-as-varia/6.0.0.Final/org/jboss/jdbc/DerbyDatabase.java

But I don't know how to apply that on recent WildFly because it looks like "mbean" and "depends" element not allowed anymore on its data source definition, and I can't find its equivalent on recent WildFly.

I think "connection-listener-class" variable of datasource definition is considerable, and it might be a way to achieve it. I haven't tried it yet but it looks like bit complex and I'm not sure it works as expected.

So, is there a way to define a shutdown-hook which executes shutdown procedure of Derby with recent WildFly?

**EDIT:**

I posted an instruction of installing Apache Derby to WildFly which includes my solution.
http://www.nailedtothex.org/roller/kyle/entry/installing-apache-derby-to-wildfly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a better solution with MBean. it simply executes the shutdown procedure at every WildFly shutdown.

Just clone [this repository](https://github.com/lbtc-xxx/derby-shutdown-service) and build a jar, put it to `$WILDFLY_HOME/standalone/deployments`. there are various files in the project so it's annoying to paste all  of files here.

A dependency to org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters, connection-listener-class and connection-listener-property are unnecessary so now `$WILDFLY_HOME/modules/org/apache/derby/main/module.xml` can be simplified like the following:

#### module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="org.apache.derby">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="derby.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

Answer (score 0):

connection-listener-class worked as I expected. I registered a listener class then Derby starts shutdown properly at every shutdown of WildFly.

But I should remember one thing - `test-connection-in-pool` won't fire connection-listener-class. if I just launch WildFly, then exec `test-connection-in-pool` to datasource of Derby, then shutdown WildFly, then the listener will never be invoked and db.lck will left undeleted. so, it might be not a ideal solution. something like more straightforward shutdown-hook would be better.

What I did are following:

1. Put derby.jar, a jar which contains ConnectionListener implementation and module.xml into `$WILDFLY_HOME/modules/org/apache/derby/main`
2. Register JDBC driver of Derby (following commands are for jboss-cli)
   `/subsystem=datasources/jdbc-driver=derby:add(driver-name=derby, driver-module-name=org.apache.derby, driver-class-name=org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver)`
3. Register a datasource
   `data-source add --name=DerbyDS --driver-name=derby --connection-url=jdbc:derby:/Users/kyle/tmp/derbytest --jndi-name=java:jboss/jdbc/DerbyDS --user-name=sa --password=sa`
4. Configure connection-listener-class
   `/subsystem=datasources/data-source=DerbyDS:write-attribute(name=connection-listener-class, value=org.nailedtothex.derby.DerbyShutdownConnectionListener)`
5. Configure connection-listener-property
   `/subsystem=datasources/data-source=DerbyDS:write-attribute(name=connection-listener-property,value={"url"=>"jdbc:derby:/Users/kyle/tmp/derbytest"}`

#### module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="org.apache.derby">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="derby.jar"/>
        <resource-root path="derby-shutdown-hook-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
        <module name="org.jboss.ironjacamar.jdbcadapters"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

#### DerbyShutdownConnectionListener.java

[Please refer GitHub for whole project contains pom.xml](https://github.com/lbtc-xxx/derby-shutdown-hook)

```
import org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.spi.listener.ConnectionListener;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class DerbyShutdownConnectionListener implements ConnectionListener {

    private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(DerbyShutdownConnectionListener.class.getName());
    private static final String DEFAULT_URL = "jdbc:derby:";
    private static final String SHUTDOWN_SUFFIX = ";shutdown=true";

    private String url;
    private String urlForShutdown;

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }

    @Override
    synchronized public void initialize(final ClassLoader classLoader) throws SQLException {
        urlForShutdown = createUrlForShutdown();
        Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                log.log(Level.INFO, "Shutdown derby. URL to use: {0}", urlForShutdown);
                shutdown(urlForShutdown);
            }
        });
        log.log(Level.INFO, "Derby shutdown hook added. URL to use: {0}", urlForShutdown);
    }

    private String createUrlForShutdown() {
        return (url == null ? DEFAULT_URL : url) + SHUTDOWN_SUFFIX;
    }

    private void shutdown(String url) {
        Connection cn = null;
        try {
            cn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            if ("08006".equals(e.getSQLState()) || "XJ015".equals(e.getSQLState())) {
                log.log(Level.INFO, "Derby shutdown succeeded. SQLState={0}", e.getSQLState());
                return;
            }
            log.log(Level.SEVERE, "Derby shutdown failed", e);
        } finally {
            if (cn != null) {
                try {
                    cn.close();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void activated(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
    }

    @Override
    public void passivated(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
    }
}
```